# Want to know upcoming id value in counter series before it get created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing a small api application. which has a model called `Book` and it has a attribute `url` . i would like to insert a value into `url` attribute like this

```
`url`: "/books/1"
```

here 1 is the record id. observe the following

```
{
"author": "Ash Maurya",
"categories": "process",
"lastCheckedOut": null,
"lastCheckedOutBy": null,
"publisher": "O'REILLY",
"title": "Running Lean",
"url": "/books/1"
```

}

How can i insert record `id` in `url` field before it get created? any ideas ? thanks in advance

i am using sqlite3 db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can do `Model.maximum(:id).next`, it's not a great idea to make a url public before it exists, in case it changes.